# how to properly transfer user input from index to invoice?

Tags: php, forms, post

I got a dillema, I'm trying to find a solution for my code.  How do I make it so that when the user inputs a given quantity in the text box from the index.php it will transfer that input quantity to the invoice.php.  I've tried doing the post method but it seems like it's not working :/  As always, any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!  I hope it's something simple:(  Here's my code:

This code holds my products array and also includes my text box.

```
//The following arrays contain our products and their information, one product per array.

$hulkhamburger = array('Product' => 'Hulk Hamburger', 'Description' => '...', 'Price' => '$1.00', 'Quantity' => "<input type='text' name='quantity1'>");
$atomichotdog = array('Product' => 'Atomic Hot Dog', 'Description' => '...', 'Price' => '$2.00', 'Quantity' => "<input type='text' name='quantity2'>");
$friedchicken = array('Product' => 'Fantastic 4 Fried Chicken', 'Description' => '...', 'Price' => '$3.00', 'Quantity' => "<input type='text' name='quantity3'>");
$psyonicpizza = array('Product' => 'Psyonic Pizza', 'Description' => '...', 'Price' => '$4.00', 'Quantity' => "<input type='text' name='quantity4'>");
$marvelmeatloaf = array('Product' => 'Marvel Meatloaf', 'Description' => '...', 'Price' => '$5.00', 'Quantity' => "<input type='text' name='quantity5'>");

//The following array takes our previous five arrays and puts them into one array for easier coding and reading.

$allfood = array ($hulkhamburger, $atomichotdog, $friedchicken, $psyonicpizza, $marvelmeatloaf);


?>
```

index.php

```
<html>
    <style>
            body{
            background-image: url('URL HERE');
            font-family: "Helvetica";
            font-size:15px;
            }

            h1{
            color:black;
            text-align:center;
            }

            p{
            font-size:15px;
            }
        </style>
        <h1>
        STORE TITLE HERE
        </h1>
    <body>       
        <form action="login.php" method="post">

            <?php
            //Include products info.inc (Which holds all our product arrays and info)
            //Credit: Tracy & Mark (THank you!)
            include 'products_info.inc';

            /*The following code centers my table on the page, makes the table background white,
             makes the table 50% of the browser window, gives it a border of 1 px,
             gives a padding of 2 px between the cell border and content, and gives 1 px of spacing between cells.
             */

            echo "<table align=center bgcolor='FFFFFF' width=50% border=1 cellpadding=1
            cellspacing=2>";

            //Credit: Tracy & Mark (THank you!)
            echo '<th>Product</th> <th>Description</th> <th>Price</th> <th>Quantity</th>';

            //The following code loops through the whole table body and then prints each row.
            for($i=0; $i<count($allfood); $i++)
                {
                //Credit: Tracy & Mark (THank you!)
                echo "<tr align=center>";
                echo "<td>{$allfood[$i]['Product']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$allfood[$i]['Description']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$allfood[$i]['Price']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$allfood[$i]['Quantity']}</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                }

            //This code ends the table.
            echo "</table>";
            echo "<br>";
            ?>
            <br><center><input type='submit' name='purchase' value='Purchase'></center>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's my invoice.php

```
<html>
    <style>
        body{
            background-image: url('URL HERE');
            font-family: "Helvetica";
            font-size:15px;
            }

            h1{
            color:black;
            text-align:center;
            }

            p{
            font-size:15px;
            }
        </style>
        <h1>
        Invoice
        </h1>
</html>

<?php
//Include products info.inc (Which holds all our product arrays and info)
//Credit: Tracy & Mark (Thank you!)
include 'products_info.inc';

//Display the invoice & 'WELCOME USER. THANK YOU FOR USING THIS DAMN THING msg'

/*The following code centers my invoice table on the page, makes the table background white,
makes the table 50% of the browser window, gives it a border of 1 px,
gives a padding of 2 px between the cell border and content, and gives 1 px of spacing between cells.
*/
echo "<table align=center bgcolor='FFFFFF' width=50% border=1 cellpadding=1cellspacing=2>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align=center><b>Product</b></td>";      
echo "<td align=center><b>Quantity</b></td>";
echo "<td align=center><b>Price</></td>";
echo "<td align=center><b>Extended Price</b></td>";
echo "</tr>";


 for($i=0; $i<count($allfood); $i++)
 {
     //Credit: Tracy & Mark (Thank you!)
     $qty= @$_POST['Quantity']['$i'];

    // This calculates the price if the user orders more than 1 item.
     $extendedprice = $qty*$allfood[$i]['Price'];

     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td align=center>{$allfood[$i]['Product']}</td>";
     echo "<td align=center>$extendedprice</td>";
     echo "<td align=center>{$allfood[$i]['Price']}</td>";
     echo "</tr>";          
 }
// The goal here was to make it so that if the user selected a certain quantity from index.php, it would carry over and display on the invoice.php
if ($qty = 0)
{
    echo "please choose 1";
}
 elseif ($qty > 0) 
{
    echo $qty;
}


/*echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align=center>Subtotal</b></td>";      
echo "<td align=center></td>";      
echo "<td align=center></td>";   

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align=center>Tax at 5.75%</td>";      
echo "<td align=center></td>";      
echo "<td align=center></td>";   

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align=center><b>Grand total</b></td>";      
echo "<td align=center></td>";      
echo "<td align=center></td>";   
*/
echo "</table>";

?>
<br>
<center>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="home" value="Back to homepage">
    </form>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

As in index.php inside form you have created table. There is no form elements like text box, hidden field. Form does not post table values hence you are not getting any posted value in  invoice.php.

Answer (score 0):

In index.php, your form action is "login.php", not invoice.php, so it will not pass anything to the latter.

Also, in index.php, there is no textbox named "quantity", so $_POST['quantity] will have nothing.

Comment: yah, I was suppose to go through a user login first, but before that wanted to make sure the quantity works.  thank you!  I'll apply your suggestions :)

Comment: yaa, to do that, just add a textbox with proper name (<input type ="text" name = "Quantity">) and change the form action to invoice.php, then you can get value in $_POST['Quantity']. Also I see in invoice.php, you have array $_POST['Quantity']['$i'], in that case you might want to name textbox as "Quantity[]"

Comment: will try :) sorry for the questions. I'm just new to coding.. and by new I mean, learning how to speak for the first time new! :)

Answer (score 0):

A form is like a container which handles transfer of data. The action attribute tells where your data will be sent.

Here you got

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
```

Which means the form data will be sent to login.php page. Not what you want i think.

Then, in the target page (defined by action attribute), you can get your parameters values in `$_GET` or `$_POST` arrays, depending of the method attribute of your form.

I don't see any textbox in the code you gave us. If you add something like

```
<input type="text" name="my_textbox"/>
```

You will be able to get the value of the textbox in your target page by using

```
$_POST['my_textbox']
```

Hope this helps.

BTW, i notices some mistakes into your code :

index.php :

1. Style should be in a `<head>...</head>` markup
2. You should not have html output like your `<h1>` outside of your `<body>...</body>`
3. Tables headers (`<th>`) should be in a `<tr>` as `<td>` are.

invoice.php :

1. $allfood is not declared
2. Better than `$qty= @$_POST['Quantity']['$i']` (@ removes errors), test if your key exists `(if isset($_POST['Quantity']) && isset($_POST['Quantity'][$i]) $qty = $_POST['Quantity'][$i];`
3. `if ($qty = 0)` should be `if ($qty == 0)` : `=` is affectation operator, `==` is comparison operator
4. same thing for html, all your output should be in `<body>...</body>` markups, and  styles should be in an html header (`<head>...</head>`)

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  I'll go back and try out you suggestions :)